# Are there any plans to get Craft Docs in Dash App

Tags: documentation

I use [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash) to browse docs and was wondering if there are any plans to get Crafts docs into it. If it's not too difficult I'd like to request it for the future (eventually).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We've discussed it off and on because so many people have requested it and have got some ideas on how we'd tackle it.  No ETA, but it's on “The List” ™.

Answer (score 7):

I spent a couple of hours this evening knocking together a Dash docset for Craft and have posted it up on Github at https://github.com/cole007/craftcms-dash/

Images are hotlinked from the source documentation so won't show offline but wanted to keep it lean.

Please feel free to fork/pull request if you find any errors or can suggest any improvements.

Comment: Thanks for making this available, Cole! I tried to make a decent docset and failed, so I'm as impressed as I am thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of people have requested this, either to P&T or directly to Kapeli... When talking to Kapeli, he basically says "here's instructions on how to do it yourself". So, if you feel like starting a repo for it, I'm sure some other folks would jump on board. :)

> https://twitter.com/kapeli/status/483392793566781441

Comment: Ironically the largest hurdle is that the docs are managed in Craft, so there's not an easy "static" representation of them to easily use his instructions with.

Comment: @BradBell That was what stopped me. I was working on a script to strip down the docs and generate a Dash docset, but I gave up when I realized the docs just aren't that easy to map to a Dash set without reorganizing and therefore mangling.

Comment: @MattStein Yeah, there is going to have to be a Craft Dash plugin that does the heavy lifting before using their recommended ways of generating the docset.